# How to move wp-admin login page to another location?

Tags: wp-admin, login

I want to move login page physically (not virtually). Please, suggest a plugin way to do this which could alter core codes on fly (even after core code update). It can be another layer of security.

Comment: You can also try this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ozh-simpler-login-url/

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion about this Question? What about the top voted Answers?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the wp-login page from your functions by hooking into login_head:

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_die');
```

(that's obviously a very clumsy way of doing it, but it prevents anyone from being able to login through that page. You could make that a redirect function, or a warning message, rather than just a die.)

And copy the existing wp-login file to another location, making sure to update the relative path to `wp-load.php` near the top (and any other relative paths that may be in there, including the links to itself and the form actions.

*(Obviously you'll have to remove the action that you added to `login_head` here, otherwise you won't be able to login from this page either.)*

Then, you should just need to add a filter to `login_url` that returns the address of your new login page, otherwise people requesting wp-admin files will be redirected to the old login page, which is now disabled.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a great security idea because the wp-login or wp-admin page in of itself does not pose a security threat. Though it can be argued that if someone had your password/username they might not be able to find where to login, thus security through obscurity.

As kronus said you could probably to some fancy re-directs, not sure how well that would scale with future releases or if it is even worth the trouble, personally I don't think its worth it and I take security seriously.

I would suggest some better ideas for your login.

Enable ssl for the login/admin (htpps).

Password protect your page using .htaccess ( so you will have a double login).

Use a plugin like Limit Login Attempts, which locks out a user after failed logins.

Comment: Thanks for your nice suggestions, but I want to move login page to another location.

Comment: It's absolutely a good idea. Hiding the fact that your site is driven by wordpress discourages people from trying to hack the core structure. If I was trolling for wordpress blogs and www.site.com/wp-login.php and came up with a 404 error I would move on without trying to break through known php exploits. Every bit of security helps make your site that much more bulletproof.

Comment: And a known core exploit would be? Ya you don't have or know of any, so your talking for nothing. Security professional actually secure applications and don't hide things, that's for children.

Comment: I never said core exploits. There are hacks-a-plenty for wordpress plugins, themes, etc. Just take a look at any exploit reporting site. Looking at the failed http request logs, sites I manage get brute force and XSS attacks _tailored for wordpress_ all day, every day. By your logic, you also shouldn't move `wp-content` outside of the root install folder, `wp-config.php` above the root folder, remove "powered by wordpress" in the page footer, change the default `wp_` table prefix or delete the default admin account. Modifying defaults *is* securing, and the login page is no different.

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers were especially useful. I question the motives of the OP, but here is how to do it. Add this to your functions.php, but make sure to replace "$login_page_id":

```
// This will redirect the actual login page to your new page
add_action( 'login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect' );
function custom_login_redirect()
{
    if ( 'wp-login.php' == $GLOBALS['pagenow'] )
    {
        // Set your $login_page_id
        wp_redirect( get_permalink($login_page_id) );
        die;
    }
}

// This will replace the login url used by Wordpress
add_filter( 'login_url', 'custom_login_url', 10, 2 );
public function custom_login_url( $login_url='', $redirect='' )
{
    // Set your $login_page_id
    return get_permalink($login_page_id);
}
```

On your new login page, you can simply add this function to show a login form:

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

Comment: I ended up creating a plugin that handles this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/sewn-in-template-log-in/

Answer (score 3):

OP, the best thing you could for this matter is IP filtering and allow only those networks that are allowed to login to the WP-Admin area (e.g. your office IP, developers' IP, etc.).

```
## .htaccess inside the wp-admin folder
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: With recent Apache versions, this would be replaced simply by `require ip xx.xx.xx.xx`, I think.

Answer (score 3):

In the five years that this question has been here, nobody has addressed the core issue: **Security by obscurity is a *valid* technique to ward off automated bots and keep the logs clean.** The goal of moving/hiding `wp-admin` is to appear to a bot that this is *not* a WordPress site.

The way that I hide (but not move) `wp-admin` is to present to bots the standard 404 page when they try to access that URL. Only access from my home IP address allows the `wp-admin` page to return properly. **This method looks to an attacker/bot as if `wp-admin` does not exist, yet it does not break core WP code or plugins that hard-code the `wp-admin` path.** This `.htaccess` code does the deed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule ^/?wp-admin - [R=404,L]
```

Of course, when using the code replace `12.34.56.78` with [your own IP address](http://simplesniff.com/). Don't forget to escape the `.` characters as the IP address is interpreted as a regex.

Comment: This is not a solution since vast majority of people have dynamic IP as well as I might want to login to my admin panel from the phone

Comment: @TheGodfather: Then [update the RewriteCond accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653461/redirect-a-range-of-ips-using-rewritecond)

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution for moving the Wordpress login from `/login/`, `/wp-admin/` or `/wp-login.php` to `/cms` using only `.htaccess` rewrite rules.

**No plugin needed!**

Paste this into the .htaccess file of the root of the project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      # Move login to /cms.
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/cms(.*)$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
      RewriteRule ^(.*) ./cms?message=wrong_login_path [R=302,L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^cms=unlocked
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
      RewriteRule ^(.*) ./cms?message=redirect_to_custom_login_path [R=302,L]
      RewriteRule ^cms wp-login.php?cms=unlocked [L]
</IfModule>
```

Cheers!

**Update:**
I improved some rules so even the `POST` requests to /wp-login.php will trigger a `403 forbidden error`. This will help against bots that are trying to login to the dashboard using brute-force methods. Feel free to comment on this post if you have any improvements to these rules.

Answer (score 2):

Just build out new login pages in subdirs. Copy the existing wp-login page into a new directory in your webroot (maybe "/login"), rename it index.php, add a WordPress bootstrap to the top of the page, and do whatever you like with it (theming, etc).

You do have to adjust the login page's default code a bit, mostly to find/replace for hardcoded links and redirects to "wp-login.php". But as long as you leave all the hooks and filters in place, this approach won't mess up any plugin integration. And WordPress core updates are fine, unless the update includes changes to the wp-login page itself (which rarely happens in minor versions).

You can also build out user account pages this way (I put them in the dir "/profile"). Once you've done that, subscriber-level users should never need to go into wp-admin, so you can protect it with an htaccess file. This is the part that actually gives you the added security you were looking for. Just be sure to make an exception in your htacces for the admin-ajax file, since some plugins use it on the frontend.

Pretty sure you're not going to find a plugin-only solution. But if you do, let us know!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-login/

You can just create a page and tell the plugin that's where the login is. But all it basically does is redirect wp-login.php to your "page". So any bot searching for wp-login.php will just be redirected to your "page".

To protect you login page from bots you should use a combination of a cookie and .htaccess as most bots don't use cookies. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^PHPSESSID=\w+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)?example\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^wp-(comments-post|login|register)\.php http://example\.com [R=301,L,NS]
```

In the example above I'm using a PHP Session Cookie, since it's the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an addition to dotancohen because it is incomplete.  dotancohen's answer does not account for `wp-login.php`, which you should consider if you're trying to obscure WordPress.

Here's how you 404 on both `wp-admin` and `wp-login.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+wp-(admin|login)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the `.htaccess` and perform a redirect to another path of your convenience.

Comment: Are you talking about URL Rewrite using .htaccess? Isn't it break internal core functions?

Comment: Well... if you do it correctly doesn't need to break anything. Reading your _update_ I will suggest rename (or move) your login things to another directory/path. What do you have in mind? Another sub-domain? or just another path?

Comment: Just another path..

Comment: Well then you can do a _Search&Replace_ in all the wordpress files, then rename the files who has the same pattern, and then rename the folder `wp-admin`. Its a little bit tricky and you will be attached to that version (any update, will broke this changes)

Answer (score 0):

To modify logout URL (in admin) edit your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'custom_logout_url');
function custom_logout_url( $login_url)
{
   $url = str_replace( 'wp-login', 'your_logout_file', $login_url );
   return $url;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I solved this problem by deleting three of my blogs and changing the parameters of limit-login to the maximums possible. 9999

For the one scum spammer at 208.91.199.94 who has hit my login page 750 times in the last two days, I am working on eliminating him other ways.