# Rewrite the HTML markup of wp-login.php

Tags: theme-development

How can I completly rewrite the markup of the login page in wordpress? I dont want to just change labels or the logo... I need to completly rewrite the structure of the page.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/10154/12615)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to customize *directly* the login page because it contains lots of  important mechanisms that is better to keep working.

Even the **plugins that customize the login page** ([A5 Custom Login Page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-page/) and [Custom Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login/) for example) don't let you change the semantic structure of the page, but just take action to some graphic elements (colors, background, etc.)

So I would suggest you to **change your login page via css**, using the classes and the identifiers defined by wordpress and listed in the [Customizing the Login Form page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form):

```
body.login {}
body.login div#login {}
body.login div#login h1 {}
body.login div#login h1 a {}
body.login div#login form#loginform {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p label {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_login {}
body.login div#login form#loginform input#user_pass {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.forgetmenot {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.forgetmenot input#rememberme {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.submit {}
body.login div#login form#loginform p.submit input#wp-submit {}
body.login div#login p#nav {}
body.login div#login p#nav a {}
body.login div#login p#backtoblog {}
body.login div#login p#backtoblog a {}
```

If all this still does not distract you from your purpose, you can always **change the file wp-login.php** into your root (I repeat: don't do it!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want change completely the login page, it's better create *another* login page:

1. create a page template with your customized login form and what else you want.
2. in WP admin create a page, title it "Login Page" and assign the template created at 1.
3. in functions.php put following code to redirect user to your login page:

   ```
   function my_login_redirect() {
     $loginpage = get_page_by_title('Login Page');
     global $pagenow;
     if ( $loginpage && ('wp-login.php' == $pagenow) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink($loginpage) );
        exit;
     }
   }
   add_action('init', 'my_login_redirect');
   ```

Of course your page template must implement all the logic for authenticate users, logout them and remember password. But looking at the code of `wp-login.php` in the root folder of WP will sure help you in this job.